# LINQ implementation - one loop or many?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have something like `collection.Select(..).Where(...).Sum(...)`

Will the LINQ engine do 1 or multiple loops over the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a single loop for the three commands.

If you like further information I recomment [Jon Skeet's blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/LINQ/default.aspx), where he describes a reimplementation of LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Are there more complex queries, when there will be more loops?

Comment: You could create some. There are commands that require running through the complete Collection like OrderBy() for example.

Comment: @Mary, yes, some operators require looking at all of the items before continuing, such as GroupBy.  If you were to combine multiple GroupBy's then multiple interations through the data would occur (although the next iteration would be over the groups instead of each individual entry).  There will also be higher overhead if there is a subquery, like list.where(x=> list.count(x) > 2);.  The subquery will cause a separate loop for each list item.

Answer (score 8):

`Sum` will consume the output of the filter `Where`, which will consume the output of the projection `Select`, which will consume the `collection`. `Sum` will walk the filtered sequence once, which will walk the projection once, which will walk the `collection` once. Therefore, the collection will be iterated over exactly one time.

Here's a cute experiment you can do to see this:

```
class Sequence : IEnumerable<int> {
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
int sum = sequence.Select(x => 2 * x).Where(x => x % 4 == 0).Sum();
Console.WriteLine("Sum is {0}", sum);
```

The output will be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
Sum is 144
```

showing that `sequence` is iterated exactly once.

Comment: I salute the effort of sample code.  However, showing that a Sequence instance is only enumerated once is not sufficient to demonstrate that the result of Select and result of Where are not separately enumerated.

Comment: @David B: Of course it's not, but it should give the OP a feel for what is going on. The only way to fully demonstrate that the sequence is only enumerated once is to understand the implementation of LINQ. I specified in the opening paragraph of my answer why it _should_ be the case that the input sequence is only iterated over once (`Sum` consumes its sequence once, `Where` consumes its sequence once, `Select` consumes its sequence once and therefore the input sequence is consumed once).

Comment: A sample to show that Select and Where are not enumerated separately would require the arguments to both Select and Where to have noticeable side-effects.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, the test you specify would not separate Select and Where from OrderBy and GroupBy.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an analogy (due to Jon Skeet) that might give you a feel for what is going on here.

Suppose you have someone named Collection who has a pack of playing cards.

Beside "Collection" is "X Where X Is Not A Face Card".

Beside "Where" is "Select Conversion of Card Value to Integer"

Beside "Select" is "Sum".

You poke Sum. Sum goes into a loop.

Sum pokes Select. Select goes into a loop.

Select has nothing to give Sum, so Select pokes Where. Where goes into a loop.

Where pokes Collection.  Collection hands Where the King of Spades.

Where throws it on the floor and pokes Collection again. Collection hands Where the Queen of Diamonds, which Where throws on the floor. Where pokes Collection again and this time Collection hands Where the Three of Hearts.

Where hands the Three of Hearts to Select. Select extracts the number three and hands that to Sum. Sum adds that to zero and then goes back to the top of the loop, and pokes Select again.

Select resumes the loop, poking Where. Where resumes the loop, poking Collection over and over again until Collection gives Where something that Where accepts.

And so it goes, with Collection handing cards to Where, Where either throwing them away or passing them on to Select, and Select feeding numbers to Sum, which keeps a running total.

When Collection eventually says "no more" to Where, Where says "no more" to Select, Select says "no more" to Sum, and Sum returns the sum to you.

Comment: Very nice analogy (Jon, thanks for sharing it Eric), but the order of `Select` and `Where` are reversed from the OP's example. That said, the point is clear.